# Intellij Idea Theming - can't find the horizontal border component

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, intellij-plugin

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFgiV.png)
I can't change this element color. I tried using UI inspector, this "border" is present around toolboxes (ToolWindow) and horizontal window popups (the ui "*" borderColor works with vertical popups [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRRtI.png)).

If someone knows what's the name of this element please let me know.